# odoo Automated task to create users while add employee

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

Python script which works like automatically add user while adding the employee in employees module.

Comment: describe your question in brief

Answer (score 3):

you must override `create` function of `hr.employee` and from there you can create new `res.user` related to current employee.